# Once set parent 301 redirection then child page redirection not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am getting issues in 301 redirections

**Example 1**

I have a URL called `https://www.example.com/abc/xyz-1` and I have to redirect to `https://www.example.com/abc/xyz`

So I have tried the below code and it's working.

```
Redirect 301 /abc/xyz-1 https://www.example.com/abc/xyz
```

**Example 2**

I have one more URL that I have to redirect

`https://www.example.com/abc` to `https://www.example.com/postname` and I tried the below code and this is also working.

```
Redirect 301 /abc https://www.example.com/postname
```

Now my issue is, that once I add the above code in my htaccess then the first example stops working.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` module is usually the best choice for handling similarly matching URIs as it only matches starting part which is `/abc` in both the cases.

You should consider using `RedirectMatch` that supports regular expression for precise matching:

```bash
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/xyz-1/?$ /abc/xyz

RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/?$ /postname

RedirectMatch 301 ^/job/?$ /opening/
```

Note use of regex anchors `^` and `$` here for precise matching. e.g. `^/abc/?$` will match `/abc` or `/abc/` but won't affect `/abc/xyz-1`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sir, The first code I haven't understood.  i just shared the example of xyz-1. it can be anything like blog to redirect blogs or job-opening to redirect jobs

Comment: ok please see my updated answer and some explanation of using regex

Comment: Thank you Sir, I have tested and it's working. Actually, i have to redirect my job page to the opening page without affecting to other inner pages  RedirectMatch 301 ^/job/?$ /opening/